# How to enable vstest.console.exe logging?

Tags: testing, logging, visual-studio-2013, vstest

I am trying to see what exactly vstest command is executed when I run tests in Visual Studio 2013. How can I enable vstest.console.exe logging?

Answer (score 5):

The command executed would be VSTest.Console.exe with the relevant parameters.
Likely Visual Studio is calling this for you when you run tests:

```
VSTest.Console.exe [Path\NameOf.dll] /Logger:trx
```

To check if VSTest actually has a logger:

```
VSTest.Console.exe /ListLoggers
```

[Write your own logger for VSTest](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vikramagrawal/2012/07/26/writing-loggers-for-command-line-test-runner-vstest-console-exe/)

[More about calling VSTest.Console.exe](http://blog.fairwaytech.com/unit-testing-using-the-command-line)